# Kubernetes resource limitation for containers not working

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes setup deployed on 4 Ubuntu virtual machines with one master and 3 minions. I created a pod with one container with following resource limitation options.

```
     limits:
   cpu: 750m
   memory: 750Mi
 requests:
   cpu: 500m
   memory: 500Mi
```

Here as far as I have understood, this particular pod will not use more than 750 MB on the host machine. Container which resides in the pod is a memory intensive java process. After some time when I get the 'top' output of the host machine, I could see that java process is taking more memory (around 1GB in resident space) than allowed threshold. Is this the expected behaviour? If so what is the idea of adding resource limits.

[image]

Comment: Check your kernel CF GROUP setup to see if the limitations are applied (also see docker.log for any startup warnings regarding this)

Comment: I believe the system uses working set and not RSS to identity a violation (RSS may include pages the process doesn't need). I also don't think it invokes the oom killer for eviction unless there's memory pressure.